# How to pass jquery function event on element that will be created in the future

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I hope I can explain my self good.
I want to create a function that has arguments which one of the arguments is a jQuery function that would be executed on event of an element that would be created after the call of the original function (it is very similar to dialog). Here is the code of what I am trying to do:

```
function messageBox(messageOptions) {
    var default_args = {
        'header': null,
        'text': null,
        'acceptButtonText': 'ok',
        'acceptButtonOnClickFunction': null,
        'cancelButtonText': 'cancel',
        'cancelButtonOnClickFunction': function() {
            $('#cancel_message_box_div_button_span').click(function() {
                $('.greyBackground').remove();
            })
        }
    };
    for (var index in default_args) {
        if (typeof messageOptions[index] == "undefined") messageOptions[index] = default_args[index];
    }

    putGrayBackground();
    var messageBoxElement = '<div class="messageBoxDiv">';
    messageBoxElement += '<legend class="messageBoxDivHeader">';
    messageBoxElement += messageOptions.header;
    messageBoxElement += '</legend>';
    messageBoxElement += '<div class="messageBoxDivText">';
    messageBoxElement += messageOptions.text;
    messageBoxElement += '</div>';
    messageBoxElement += '<div class="messageBoxDivButtons">';
    messageBoxElement += '<div id="cancel_message_box_div_button_span" class="messageBoxDivButtonSpan">';
    messageBoxElement += messageOptions.cancelButtonText;
    messageBoxElement += '</div>';
    messageBoxElement += '</div>';
    messageBoxElement += '</div>';
    $('.greyBackground').append(messageBoxElement);
}​
```

The code suppose to create an element that has a span which when it would be clicked will call the function under 'cancelButtonOnClickFunction' argument. 
As you can see there are default parameters, one of them is 'cancelButtonOnClickFunction'. After I have created the element I append it, I think it doesn't works because the 'cancelButtonOnClickFunction' inner function is called before the element is created. I would ask how to make it work.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, but it looks a lot like you are trying to make things more difficult than they are. Should `cancelButtonOnClickFunction` always be the function that is executed when the event `$('#cancel_message_box_div_button_span').click` happens? Or should it be a function that can define different events (which is sort of what it is now)?

Comment: execute when the event $('#cancel_message_box_div_button_span').click happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that your code is executed too early. In fact it isn't executed at all! Let's just get to fixing the code and along the way we will learn why the original your version didn't work.

First, we change something in your default arguments:

```
    [..]
    'cancelButtonOnClickFunction': function() {
            $('.greyBackground').remove();
        })
    [..]
```

Basically, you would want your users to define their event handler (or callback) in exactly the same way they would if they were using jquery directly, so you should be doing the same thing in your default argument.

Now here is the catch: you are not executing a function here. You are defining a function and assigning that function to the `cancelButtonOnClickFunction` property. This is possible because in javascript, functions are first class citizens. In less fancy words, that means that functions are "values" in much the same way numbers, strings and (other) objects are and as such, you can do a lot of things with them like using them as arguments or assigning them to variables. (In fact, in javascript `function a() {alert('a')}` is just another way to write `var a = function() {alert('a')}`, but I am getting way off track here.)

Alright, so now that we got that piece of code down, we now need to make sure that the event is connected correctly. Because we aren't stuck doing this at the top of the function, we can just do so after the html has been generated and we won't have to worry about the assignment happening before the html is in place anymore:

```
    [..]
    $('.greyBackground').append(messageBoxElement);
    $('#cancel_message_box_div_button_span').click(messageOptions.cancelButtonOnClickFunction);
}
```

And that's it, here we just supply the variable that holds the function instead of providing an anonymous function like we are used to when normally working with jquery. These two changes should solve the code and make sure it does what you want it to do. And hopefully my explanation along the way helped you understand a little more about the how and why.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with using an event handler within a function though it can get quite messy. I have an alternative solution for you below for the event handling.

As for the `messageOptions`, you can use another jQuery function to combine the objects. This is how jquery-ui combines their default settings with settings you provide in their widgets.

```
$.extend(default_args, messageOptions)
```

The above would replace your for loop and removing the piece of code that looks to be causing you problems. Instead of calling messageOptions.header further down you would now always use your default_args object.

```
messageBoxElement += default_args.header
```

Event handling

If you take a lower level parent and use `.on` you can bind click events to any elements whether they exist yet or not. This works by binding the event to the non changing element and then bubbling up when any child element is clicked and meets its conditions (second parameter). You would use this in your document.ready function:

```
$('#message_box_container').on('click', '#cancel_message_box_div_button_span', function(e)
{
    $('.grey-background').remove();
});
```

Comment: This looks like an ugly hack that is only necessary because the question is unclear. If the asker would tell us more about what he wants to happen, we could actually provide code that does what he wants, which I would take over an ugly hack any day of the week.

Comment: This is not an ugly hack, `.on()` is the recommended replacement to `.live()` as of jQuery 1.7. The function was specifically designed to fulfil this purpose. See : [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Well, unless you know something I don't, it isn't clear what "this purpose" is. In fact, while I don't know what "this purpose" is, I have a strong suspicion it isn't what you are making it out to be (much as I doubt the askers assumption why it doesn't work is correct).

Comment: Well, the question is not very clear, but it is there. He wants to know how he can run a click event on piece of html that he is yet to create. Read the OP's final paragraph carefully and you will see that his code matches with what he is asking. The above piece of code will fulfil that requirement for him.

Comment: Well, as I interpret it, the problem isn't that he wants to execute before it is created, but is having trouble passing the parameter around before the html is created and is afraid this fails because the function is executed to early. However, he never uses `cancelButtonOnClickFunction`, so I think instead it never gets executed, which means that the real problem isn't that it is executed before the html is generated and thus you fix (on its own) won't solve the problem. As I see it, it is about variables (parameters in this case) referring to functions instead.

Comment: And that is precisely what the above code accomplishes, I have edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18498/discussion-between-jasper-and-david-barker)

Comment: I will try explain my self better: I have the 'messageBox(messageOptions)' (messageOptions can contain {header: , text: ,...} and so on) function when it is called (and it is called when some element is clicked) I want to create a complex element that has a span that id is 'cancel_message_box_div_button_span'. Now I want to add a function that would be executed when this 'cancel_message_box_div_button_span' is clicked. No I want to give the user of the function change what the clicking of 'cancel_message_box_div_button_span' would do. by default it is removing 'greyBackground' class element.